# Column order of the predict function for an xgboost model

Tags: r, predict

Does anyone know if the columns in the newdata in the R predict function need to be in the exact same order as the traindata on which the predictive model was built using xgboost? And is it a problem if the newdata has extra columns? In the example below it seems that a different order / extra columns gives different predictions.

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars <- subset(mtcars, select = c(qsec, mpg, drat))
mtcars <- as.matrix(mtcars)
dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(data = mtcars[,c(2:3)], label=mtcars[,1])
mod <- xgboost(data = dtrain, nrounds = 10)
nd1 <- data.frame(mpg=20, drat=3)
nd2 <- data.frame(drat=3, other=100, mpg=20)
nd3 <- data.frame(drat=3, mpg = 20)
nd4 <- data.frame(mpg=20, other=100, drat=3)

predict(mod, as.matrix(nd1))
# 16.4753
predict(mod, as.matrix(nd2))
# 14.3291
predict(mod, as.matrix(nd3))
# 14.3291
predict(mod, as.matrix(nd4))
# 15.71044
```

Comment: It appears to ignore names. Example: `nd4 <- data.frame(mpg=20, other=3) ;
predict(mod, newdata = as.matrix(nd4))`
# 16.4753`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, one should keep columns in the exact same order in order to get the correct result. It is mentioned in the following link 
[test set column order](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/636)